# When I specify NodePort service as Ingress backend in GKE, I get two backends

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, gke-networking

**-- Overview**

I have a custom installation of istio on GKE (type=nodeport). The installation commands are as follows

```
istioctl install --set profile=default --set values.gateways.istio-ingressgateway.type=NodePort
```

I'm building Ingress and specifying the NodePort service as the backend.  I found that another backend specified set by GCP as a default even though I specified NodePort. So, I couldn't connect to GCP LoadBalancer via TCP/IP. If I set the same port as the pod's readinessprobe for ingress and so on, the health checks look there too.
Are there any way to solve this?

**-- Detail**

- Detail view of an LB with two backends (the top backend service is the default configuration in GCP)

[Detail view of LB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve7nl.png)

- NodePort configuration

```
# This is a value that is automatically set by istio
$ k get svc istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system -o yaml
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 32476
    port: 15021
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15021
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 32241
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31739
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: tcp-istiod
    nodePort: 32488
    port: 15012
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15012
  - name: tls
    nodePort: 32741
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15443
```

- Setting of readiness of istio-ingressgateway(pod)

```
$ k get po istio-ingressgateway-6f8bbbbd8c-qmkln -n istio-system -o yaml
:
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 30
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz/ready
        port: 15021
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 1
      periodSeconds: 2
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

- Setting of ingress

```
# 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.custom.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 80
      - backend:
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 15021
```

- Result of `kubectl get svc`

```
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   NodePort    10.47.13.185   <none>        15021:31761/TCP,80:31561/TCP,443:31257/TCP,15012:31841/TCP,15443:32172/TCP   9h
```

Comment: Hi, do I understand correctly that you've deployed `Istio` on `GKE` (with `Ingressgateway` set to a `NodePort`) and you are additionally creating a `ingress-gce` to forward the traffic to the `Ingressgateway`? If that's correct, is there any particular reason why you are following this setup? Also, could you please edit the question and add the screenshot that you've uploaded in English?

Comment: @Dawid Kruk
>  you are additionally creating a ingress-gce to forward the traffic to the Ingressgateway?

Yes, that's correct.

> If that's correct, is there any particular reason why you are following this setup?
I want to apply CloudArmor by creating an ingress, but the ExternalLoadBalancer that is created by itself when I install istio as a LoadBalancer is created in us-east-1, and I can't apply CloudArmor.
So, if there is a way to create istio-ingressgateway as global LB, it is OK.

Comment: > add the screenshot that you've uploaded in English?   
- OK. I've fixed this.

Comment: I've looked on the setup that you are trying to implement (`Istio`: `NodePort` + `Ingress GCE`). The backend service that is targetting `port30317` is most probably referencing the `default-http-backend` (please check it with `$ kubectl get svc -A` (and look for `NodePort`)). The 2nd one will be  your `Ingressgateway` `Pod`. I see that you have some issues trying to connect with your `Ingress`. Could you tell/show the response that you are getting when trying to connect to your `Ingress`? I've used yours `Ingress` manifest and it looked like you are specifying 2 same paths to 2 different svcs.

Comment: @Dawid Kruk   Thank you for your confirmation. I'm accessing ingress with a browser from google crome, but I get `This www.custom.com page can't be found (404 NOT FOUND)`.    And the first one result of `kubectl get svc -A`, I'll update and edit the text.

Comment: I'd reckon the `Ingress` resource that you've posted is sending all of the requests to port 15021 instead of 80. You can check if that's the case by curling your `Ingress` resource on a path: `/healthz/ready`. It should give you the status of your `ingressgateway` (`200` for example)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I originally added ` servicePort: 80` as well, but it is strange that there are two backends when only port:15021 is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've divided this answer on parts:

- Two backends when creating an `Ingress` resource with `GKE`.
- Ingress definition in the question.
- Integrating `Cloud` Armor with `Istio`.

---

### Two backends when creating an `Ingress` resource with `GKE`

This is working as expected as `Ingress` created with `GKE` will have 2 backends:

- The one specified in the `YAML` manifest.
- The default backend: `default-http-backend`.

As an example you can follow below steps:

- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=NodePort`
- Create an `Ingress` resource for `nginx` but with a `hello` path (for example purposes)

After that you should be seeing a similar setup:

[image: GCP LB]

The first backend service is using an Instance group to send the requests to the default-backend that are not matching the `Ingress` resource.

The second backend service is using NEG (Network Endpoint Groups) to send the requests that are matching with the `Ingress` resource (in this example to an `nginx` `Deployment`).

I've marked the red squares to "connect it" with the Kubernetes resources (look on ports):

- `$ kubectl get svc nginx`

```sh
NAME    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx   NodePort   10.20.6.229   <none>        80:32612/TCP   51m
```

- `$ kubectl get svc -n kube-system default-http-backend`

```sh
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
default-http-backend   NodePort   10.20.15.39   <none>        80:30603/TCP   121m
```

---

#### Ingress definition in the question

The part of the `Ingress` definition that was included in the question is/was created in a way that was referencing the same paths with 2 different backends:

```
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 80
      - backend:
          serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
          servicePort: 15021
```

Above example:

- Is having 2 different backends.
- Is configured that 2 different backends share the same path.
- The requests (as I've reproduced it) were coming to the "`15021`" backend which is only for health checking.

To fix that, you will need to remove the `15021` backend and use `backendConfig` resource to configure health checking and security policy (more on that later).

> A side note!
>
> The `YAML` manifest is using and old and soon to be deprecated way to describe `Ingress`. Please refer to this documentation for more reference:
>
> - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)*

---

#### Integrating Cloud Armor with Istio

One of the ways that you can use Cloud Armor with Istio is the following:

- Create a security policy.
- Create a `backendConfig` as a prerequisite for Istio `Service`.
- Install Istio with modification to its `Service`.
- Create an `Ingress` resource to point to `istio-ingressgateway`.
- Test with an example.

#### Create a security policy

For example purposes a security policy can be created that only blocks a single IP address. It can be done either by `gcloud` or `Cloud Console` (Web UI):

- *[Cloud.google.com: Armor: Docs: Configure security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies)*

Let's assume that the security policy named: `deny-single` was created that blocks a single IP address.

#### Create a `backendConfig` as a prerequisite for Istio `Service`.

You will need to create a `backendConfig` that will configure health checks and will enforce the security policy:

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: ingress-backendconfig
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  healthCheck:
    requestPath: /healthz/ready
    port: 15021
    type: HTTP
  securityPolicy:
    name: deny-single # <-- IMPORTANT
```

#### Install Istio with modification to its `Service`

You will need to add following annotations **to the `Service` of your `istio-ingressgateway`**:

```yaml
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "ingress-backendconfig"}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
```

This annotations will inform `GCP` on the security policy to apply as well on the health checks that are required for the traffic to be passed to the `istio-ingressgateway`.

#### Create an `Ingress` resource to point to `istio-ingressgateway`

A basic `Ingress` definition that will send the request from `HTTP(S) Load Balancer` to `istio-ingressgateway` can be following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            port:
              number: 80
```

#### Test with an example

To check if the setup is working correctly you can spawn the [Bookinfo Application](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/).

Testing with 2 different IP addresses:

- `$ curl ifconfig.me`

```sh
217.AAA.BBB.CCC
```

- `$ curl 34.XXX.YYY.ZZZ/productpage`

```sh
<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>403</title>403 Forbidden%
```

- `$ curl ifconfig.me`

```sh
94.EEE.FFF.GGG
```

- `$ curl 34.XXX.YYY.ZZZ/productpage`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Bookstore App</title>
<-- REDACTED -->
```

> A side note!
>
> The "closed port" that you've received could be related to the fact that `istio-ingressgateway` was configured to listen on specific path like `/productpage` and not `/`. (if the request was specifically targeted to port `80` instead of `15021`)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Alwaysupalwayson: Posts: 2021: 04: Cloud armor](https://alwaysupalwayson.com/posts/2021/04/cloud-armor/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Standalone NEG](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg)*
- *[Istio.io](https://istio.io/)*

Comment: @Dawid Kruk   Thanks for going to the trouble of verifying all this!　I was working on something else and didn't realize it until later. Sorry about that.　I've only read about it, but it looks like it's routed correctly.　I hadn't thought about creating the backendConfig myself.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long, but I'll check it tomorrow and accept it when I'm done.

Comment: I was able to configure the ingress (LoadBalancer) backend correctly with the settings you gave me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @lulu_39 glad that you've managed to make it work. Please consider [reacting to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) either by accepting it or upvoting (if your reputation allows that). There is no obligation to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't vote right now because I'm slightly short on reputation.If I have enough after this, I will vote.  I've accepted this answer.